# How to make GNU grep the default in FreeBSD?

Tags: grep, freebsd, path, defaults

I'm running FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE. I've installed GNU grep with `portmaster textproc/gnugrep`.

However the "default" grep for users is still FreeBSD grep.

```
# /usr/local/bin/grep -V
/usr/local/bin/grep (GNU grep) 2.12

# grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

I want to make GNU grep the default. I understand that the problem is with the order of directories specified in my `PATH` environment variable:

```
# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
```

However, I fear to move the `/usr/local/bin` entry to the beginning of my `PATH`. Is it safe?

In Linux distros like Debian such tasks are usually accomplished via `dpkg-divert` and/or `update-alternatives`.

What is the best way to do what I want in FreeBSD and not break system upgrades and such?

Comment: Both of those greps claim to be Gnu Grep, one is older, and may have some FreeBSD mods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Note this answer is from 2013, it applies to FreeBSD 8.x and earlier. A [BSD grep](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep) was added in [revision 222273](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=222273) and appeared in FreeBSD-9.0 (oddly that change is missing from the usually comprehensive release notes: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bsdgrep+site:freebsd.org+inurl:relnotes)). A fully-featured GNU grep continues to be [available in the ports collection](https://www.freshports.org/textproc/gnugrep/).

---

FreeBSD `grep` <strike>*is*</strike> *was* GNU `grep`, albeit old and with a few patches applied:

```
# which grep 
/usr/bin/grep

# /usr/bin/grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It has a small number of patches (most of which originate from Fedora Linux), if you have `/usr/src/` installed those are detailed in `/usr/src/gnu/usr.bin/grep/FREEBSD-upgrade`.

If you need something specifically in the port version (2.12 vs 2.5.1) there are many bugfixes, speed improvements, and PCRE support (`-P`, not enabled in system version),  it should be quite safe to reorder your `PATH` to put `/usr/local/bin` first, this is what I usually do. (It's good practise to use `su -` so that root's environment is set correctly, though on FreeBSD the default `~root/.cshrc` sets the `PATH` explicitly.)

Otherwise check your shell man page and set an `alias` as required, but this is really only for interactive use, shell scripts or Makefiles won't observe it.

Comment: Yes, I need the `-P` switch. I'll try changing the order of the PATH. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just create an alias, in bash add to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias grep /usr/local/bin/grep
```

(I believe other shells can do something similar.) That way you can cherry pick individual executables. Even call your alias `gnugrep` if you don't want to loose the system one.

Answer (score 1):

Move only grep to start of path.

- Make a directory `mkdir /override/bin`.
- Put a symlink in this directory `ln -s /usr/local/bin/grep /override/bin/` or better (if you have gnu ln) `ln -s -t /override/bin/ /usr/local/bin/grep` (less chase of error).
- add `/override/bin/` to start of path.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your ${PATH}, alternatively you can just link to the `grep` you like from an early entry of the ${PATH} value.

for example `/bin` is the second entry of your ${PATH} and its probably in all users's ${PATH} values.

so you could do this as root:

```
cd /bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/grep
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Package managers rely on the veracity of their databases to maintain state -- that trust should not be circumvented.

Comment: @ChrisDown as far as I can tell, this solution doesn't break package manager databases. No port will install binaries to /bin ...

Comment: ok, you are right about that... alternatively. you could add something in your `~/.bashrc` like `export PATH="~/.bin:${PATH}"`. and then you link from there, like `mkdir ~/.bin; cd ~/.bin; ln -s /usr/local/bin/grep`. That way only your user is affected.

Comment: @mauro that's a clean and simple solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well... I don't see the problem with this solution, can someone explain why is it bad?

Comment: If the change should affect only your user, create an alias.

Comment: @vadipp I can't say it will cause problems with *package management*, I would not do this on FreeBSD because **1:** `grep` is used during startup (it's not invoked before filesystems are mounted, but it's a *concern*) **2:** it *might* complicate `freebsd-update` binary updates, similarly `freebsd-update IDS` if used **3:** risk of breaking things by replacing/overriding system binaries with ones that have *different* switches (e.g. GNU `sed` has no `-E`, `rc.jail` would *break* if you replaced `sed`) **4:** the alternatives (`alias` or `PATH`) are trivial.

Comment: @mr.spuratic thanks for your explanation, things really are scary :) Another solution would be to create symlink `/usr/local/bin/ggrep -> grep`. I've found this idea in GNU find, which is installed as `/usr/local/bin/gfind`. I think I'll end up changing the PATH, as everyone says it's safe.