# How to sort and filter images by modification time and view them in nsxiv on FreeBSD

Tags: shell-script, find, freebsd, sort, images

I am using [nsxiv](https://nsxiv.codeberg.page) to view JPEG and PNG images on FreeBSD. However, I am unable to find a way to sort and filter the images by modification time to view them in nsxiv on FreeBSD. On Linux with GNU coreutils and GNU findutils, I can use the command below to view images modified after 2023-10-01, sorted by modification time.

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
    \( -iregex '.+\.jpe?g$' -o -iregex '.+\.png$' \) \
    -newermt 2023-10-01 \
    -exec ls -t --zero -- {} + | \
        nsxiv -0 -
```

I am unable to find an equivalent command on FreeBSD that is able to handle filenames that contain spaces, newlines, and other unusual characters. The issue is that FreeBSD's [`ls`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) has no `--zero` option to output NUL separated filenames to pipe to `nsxiv`. Another issue is that FreeBSD's [`find`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) has no `-printf0` that could be useful for getting file modification times that can be passed to `sort -z`. How do I sort and filter images by modification time and view them in nsxiv on FreeBSD?

I am using `/bin/sh` (dash) on Linux and `/bin/sh` on FreeBSD.

Comment: I probably would have done that without `find` altogether, but my shell allows me to sort file globs anyways. What's the shell you're using?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I guess that's a pretty barebones POSIX-and-little-more shell. Hm.

Comment: That use of coreutils is also relatively recent. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option) on `--zero`. It was rejected for a long time as `ls`  was intended for human consumption.

Comment: And there is a good chance that `-printf` will land in FreeBSD `find` soonish. See [D38138](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D38138). Not helpful now but if someone sees this in the future....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works in FreeBSD's `/bin/sh`. I have tried it in FreeBSD 13.2. It seems to properly handle filenames that contain backslashes and whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines), including leading and trailing whitespace.

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
        \( -iregex '.\{1,\}\.jpe\{0,1\}g$' -o -iregex '.\{1,\}\.png$' \) \
        -newermt 2023-10-01 \
        -exec ls -l -B -D%s {} + \
    | cut -w -f6- | sort -r | cut -f2- \
    | while read -r line; do
        printf '%b\0' "$line"
      done \
    | nsxiv -0 -
```

How it works:

- `ls -l -B -D%s`

  - `-B` displays non-printable characters in octal notation. This is important for handling filenames that contain newlines and tabs.
  - `-D%s` formats file modification time in seconds since the Epoch. This will be useful for sorting by modification time.
- `cut -w -f6-`: remove all columns from the output of `ls -l ...` except the columns that contain file modification times and filenames. `-w` is necessary to make consecutive spaces count as one delimiter.
- `sort -r`: sort files by modification time from the most recently modified to the oldest.
- `cut -f2-`: remove the column of file modification times, leaving only the (newline-separated) filenames.
- The last part: read the newline-separated filenames one by one and use `printf`'s `%b` format string to convert the octal notation in the filenames back to the actual characters (i.e. including newline and tabs). Separate the filenames using the NULL character (`\0`), pipe the NULL-separated filenames into `nsxiv -0 -`.

---

Additional notes:

- `cut -w -f6- | sort -r | cut -f2-` cannot be replaced by `ls`'s `-t` option. As user "Stéphane Chazelas" wrote in another answer on this webpage:

  > [`find ... -exec ls -t ... -- {} +`] won't work properly at sorting the files by modification time if the list of files is big enough that `find` needs to invoke `ls` several times.
- `find ... \( -iregex '.\{1,\}\.jpe\{0,1\}g$' -o -iregex '.\{1,\}\.png$' \)` could be simplified by using extended regular expressions. e.g. `find -E ... -iregex '.+\.(jpe?g|png)$'`.
- In the unusual case where there are space character(s) in the owner or group names, it might be necessary to add the `-n` option to `ls`, so that `ls` outputs user ids and group ids instead of names.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to properly go through xargs to get the sorting done; so, something like

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
    \( -iregex '.+\.jpe?g$' -o -iregex '.+\.png$' \) \
    -newermt 2023-10-01 \
    -print0 \
    \|
      xargs -0 \
        stat -n -f '%Y %N\0' \
    \|
      sort -z \
    \|
      cut -z -d ' ' -f2-  \
    \|
      nsxiv -0 -
```

We use the "decorate – sort – undecorate" trick that you would normally find in languages with tuples. Here, we need to separate our sort key (the time in seconds since epoch, `%Y` in stat) from our value (the file name) with a space. And then `cut` that back out. A bit awkward!

Comment: You'd want to check the man pages of [`find`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE+and+Ports), [`stat`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) and [`cut`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) on FreeBSD. You can't assume GNUisms will work the same on FreeBSD.

Comment: Did on find and stat (that's why it's stat -f). Assumed cut would be simple enough.

Comment: @ClausAndersen aaargh thanks. Yeah, that got lost on the copy and paste from the question. Please insert it, I'm on my phone.

Comment: This solution does not work on FreeBSD. `stat`'s `%Y` format string does not represent the file modification time. `cut` has no `-z` option.

Comment: Yes, BSD stat supports different format directives from the (nonsensical) ones of GNU stat, themselves different from the (better) ones of GNU find -printf. Here,  you'd likely want `%Fm` for the mtime as a float to be used with `sort -n`. For the string `%Sm` representation, you can adapt the date format with `-t`. It also won't expand a `\0` to a NUL

Comment: BSD `find`'s regexps are standard BRE by default and standard ERE with `-E`, while for GNU find that's some regexp from some ancient version of emacs by default (can be changed with `-regextype`)

Comment: I'll be honest, I copied the match criteria from the question – I didn't intend to change it, as it "worked for user"

Answer (score 2):

If it is important for you to be able to make it work on a vanilla FreeBSD system there is another answer with find/xargs/cut/stat. If you are able to install additional utilities there is a cleaner answer using zsh as well.

But if you are used to GNUism and Linux then it is very easy to live a comfortable life on FreeBSD if you install the GNU [findutils](https://www.freshports.org/misc/findutils/).

```
pkg install findutils
```

In the same vein people have got bitten by BSD ls, grep, make, sed and awk. But their GNU counterparts are easily available as well as [gnuls](https://www.freshports.org/misc/gnuls), [gnugrep](https://www.freshports.org/textproc/gnugrep/), [gmake](https://www.freshports.org/devel/gmake/), [gsed](https://www.freshports.org/textproc/gsed/) and [gawk](https://www.freshports.org/lang/gawk/). Are you going *all in* then get [coreutils](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/coreutils/)

They can all coexist with the BSD versions on your system. You will then typically prefix the command with a "g" for the GNU version: `gnuls`, `gfind`, `gxargs`, `gmake`, `gsed` and `gawk`.

And if you hate to prefix your beloved gnu variants then see "[How to make GNU grep the default in FreeBSD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65603/how-to-make-gnu-grep-the-default-in-freebsd)"

If you get used to the BSD variants instead then they are available on Linux as well. See [bsdutils](https://github.com/dcantrell/bsdutils)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
zsh +o caseglob -c '
  autoload after
  print -rN -- *.(jp(e|)g|png)(.e[after 2023-10-01]om)' | nsxiv -0 -
```

For portability + reliability, `perl` is likely your best bet:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=lstat -MPOSIX -MFile::Glob=:nocase -e '
  $start = mktime(0,0,0, 1,10-1,2023-1900); # 2023-10-01
  for (<*.{jpg,jpeg,png}>) {
    push @files, [$_, $s[9]] if @s = lstat and -f _ and $s[9] >= $start;
  }
  print "$_->[0]\0" for sort {$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]} @files
  ' | nsxiv -0 -
```

Note that your *`-exec ls -t --zero -- {} +`* won't work properly at sorting the files by modification time if the list of files is big enough that `find` needs to invoke `ls` several times.